# PHP need E-mail back to be more "Readable"

Tags: php, forms

This is coming from my boss. I have set this up and need some help customizing the message back. 
Here is the link to the [website](http://www.airman-usa.com/site_project/contact.php).
Here is the code to the php I have set up to e-mail the contact form:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//reporting errors

if(isset($_POST["Form_Submission"])){
//Checking for blank Fields..
if($_POST["name"]==""||$_POST["email"]==""||$_POST["company"]==""||  $_POST["phone-number"]==""||$_POST["message"]==""){
echo "Please fill out all fields. Thank you.";
}else{
// Check if the "Sender's Email" input field is filled out
$email=$_POST['email']; 

// Sanitize e-mail address
$email =filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

// Validate e-mail address
$email= filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

if (!$email){
echo "Invalid Sender's Email";
 }
else{
$message ="Contact Submission: \n";
foreach ($_POST as $param_name => $param_val) {
$message .= "Name: $param_name -- Value: $param_val\n";
};
$message .= "//End Form";
$email_subject = "Form Submit";
$email = 'From:'. $email . "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
$email = 'Cc:'. $email . "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender

// message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
// Send mail by PHP Mail Function
mail($recipient, $email_subject, $message);
echo "Your mail has been sent successfuly ! Thank you for reaching out to us!";
}
}
};

?>
```

I'm trying to find where I can edit the way the e-mail looks so that my boss can read it.

Right now emails are coming back with:

Name: company -- Value: Enginovations
Name: name -- Value: Talentless Hack
Name: email -- Value: starsprintingfox@gmail.com
Name: phone-number -- Value: 7065840710
Name: message -- Value: Brooklyn lomo knausgaard, pickled sriracha twee tousled beard waistcoat before they sold out YOLO synth. Blue bottle synth bushwick dreamcatcher umami whatever, post-ironic yuccie.
Austin keffiyeh gochujang irony polaroid lo-fi, retro celiac tote bag VHS whatever bitters ugh. XOXO photo booth listicle, kitsch man bun cray dreamcatcher stumptown hammock +1. Mixtape everyday carry post-ironic taxidermy trust fund, slow-carb blue bottle ramps tilde kickstarter seitan. Kitsch bespoke venmo dreamcatcher lumbersexual, skateboard yuccie PBR&B kombucha. Humblebrag crucifix microdosing, butcher selvage waistcoat four dollar toast artisan narwhal.
Name: Form_Submission -- Value: Send Feedback //End Form

He wants the e-mails to come back to read:
Name:
Company:
Phone Number:
E-mail:
Message:

That's it. No variable tag on it. I don't know where to look. I don't even think you can do that really.

Comment: If it's just for your boss, use firebug and screen haha. Sorry ^^. You can read the documentation for the mail function. You can add header for use html in your mail, so you can design they like you want.

`// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";`EDIT : the link :http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Alex Howansky.

Comment: @Xenofex Thanks I'll give this a go